# Is $\frac{1}{\min(\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b})}=\max(a,b)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is $\frac{1}{\min(\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b})}=\max(a,b)$?

How, would one proof something like this?

Comment: Without loss of generality, let a>b. Then 1/a<1/b and 1/min(1/a,1/b) = 1/(1/a) = a = max(a,b). This only works if a and b are positive, though.

Comment: Mind putting it as answer so you can get appropriate credit.

Comment: There is a brutal method in which you write out the formula for $\min$ and do a lot of algebra, but it reduces to whatever answer has been provided here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $0 < a < b$

Then $\frac 1 a > \frac 1 b > 0$

Then $\frac 1{\min(1/a, 1/b)} = b = \max (a, b)$

---

Let $a < b < 0$

Then $1/b < 1/a < 0$

Then $\frac 1{\min(1/a, 1/b)} = b = \max(a, b)$

---

HOWEVER

Let $a < 0 < b$

Then $\frac 1 a < 0 < \frac 1 b$

Then $\frac 1 {\min(1/a, 1/b)} = a = \color{red}{\min(a, b)}$

---

Conclusion: It does not hold for all values.  The statement is only true when the values have the same signage.